# Python: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' at line 269 plus more

Tags: python

I have a python code that I got from someone that gets football stats from a certain link, but once it gets to a certain player, that player being Cooper Kupp, it bring me to the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AP MVP-3, AP OPoY-5, AP ORoY-2, AP1, PB'`, at line 269, and at line 1154: `player_recur(pos,writer,name,table)`. Here is the link to the code, I cant paste it all here because of limits: https://pastebin.com/bvh8HK2w

Comment: At line 269 you have this `age = re.findall(agestring)`  but you never define `agestring` in your full code check this [link](https://i.ibb.co/6FG4Q3J/Untitled.png) also `re.findall requires 2 arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: `re.findall` also requires to arguments, a pattern and a string to search in.

Comment: I removed that, the error on line 269 is about ```age = age + float(i[0])```

Comment: @WorldMapper2 Real error is `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AP MVP-3, AP OPoY-5, AP ORoY-2, AP1, PB'` it shows that the float got the value to convert is `'AP MVP-3, AP OPoY-5, AP ORoY-2, AP1, PB'` so the float cannot convert this to float.

Comment: Its trying to find the players Awards, which I don't want.